# How to get the actual values from OutboundJaxrsResponse in java?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

In my RestClient returns below response to my jersey service. 
OutboundJaxrsResponse{status=200, reason=OK, hasEntity=true, closed=false, buffered=false}

The above one returns the list. How can I get the list and how to validate each record id? If id is not available in my database need to store missing id. how to handle this?

Below is  my code;

```
public Response list() throws Exception {
    Response response = null;
    RestClient client = service.getClient();
    try {
        response = client.invokeServiceGETForArray(serviceType, "/test/name", null, null);
JsonArray responseLst = (JsonArray)     response.readEntity(JsonArrayBuilder.class);
System.out.println("Response Array List :: "   +  responseLst);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getLocalizedMessage()).build();
    }
    return response;
}
```

above code snippet returns the below response :
   **OutboundJaxrsResponse{status=200, reason=OK, hasEntity=true, closed=false, buffered=false}**
I am trying to read response using below code :
***JsonArray responseLst = (JsonArray) response.readEntity(JsonArrayBuilder.class);
But it is throwing below exception.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method not supported on an outbound message.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(OutboundJaxrsResponse.java:145)***

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can't do this. Outbound `Response`s are only meant for the server side. Even so, what you are trying to do is not a good idea. You are trying to completely change the response, which doesn't give the user any chance to get information from the _real_ `Response`.

Comment: I am trying to read the response object using this code " JsonArray responseLst = (JsonArray) response.readEntity(JsonArrayBuilder.class); ", but this throwing an error,  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method not supported on an outbound message.